# Toolbar com separador na parte inferior

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou a utilizar a `Toolbar`, mas queria que a parte inferior dela ficasse com uma linha de outra cor que a delimitasse, como mostra a imagem,

[image: Tela com uma toolbar no topo em tom predominentemente cinza claro, mas com um separador cinza escuro entre ela e o restante da tela]

Para conseguir este efeito a unica coisa que me lembro é utilizar um `ImageView`. Existe alguma outra maneira melhor de fazer isto?

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de uma *ImageView* use uma *View* com o *background* da cor que pretende e defina a altura em `android:layout_height`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        ........
        ........
        ........>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/LinhaHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height= "2dp"
        android:background="@color/gray" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Não funciona. Meti exactamente como disseste mas fica igual, sem a barra a cinzento :\

Comment: Funciona, tens é de aumentar o valor do `layout_height`.

Comment: Não vai é ocupar todo o Toobar, apenas a parte central entre o icon de navegação à esquerda e pontos do menu à direita. Caso não utilizes nenhum deles a linha pode ser estendida a todo o comprimento usando `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` e `app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"`